# Error page not seeing Server.GetLastError as having an error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following block of code in the `Page_load` event of my custom error page:

```
Dim objError As Exception
objError = Server.GetLastError()

If IsError(objError) Then
    lblStackTrace.Text = objError.StackTrace
    lblSource.Text = objError.Source
    lblMessage.Text = objError.Message
Else
    MsgBox("Not an Error")
End If
```

Every time I trigger an error, and get sent to my page via web.config, I get the "Not an Error" box, even though I know it just threw an error.  Am I not implementing this correctly?  I'm trying to write the details of the error to the page (as a stepping stone to automatically firing an email with the details in it) but I'm getting hung up actually catching the error it seems.

Edit:
Web.config block:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="http://localhost:60470/ErrorPages/GenericError.aspx" mode="On">
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, custom Error pages from web.config do not have access to the error.

See :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa479319.aspx#customerrors_topic1

> Further, a custom error page (as set in web.config) does not have
>   access to the last error thrown, so it is really only useful to make
>   the apology prettier.

please see :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa479319.aspx#customerrors_topic7

for a rich custom error page handling

Hope this will help

Comment: It certainly will.  Thank you.